# CakePHP request data limits

Tags: php, forms, cakephp-2.3

When I try to send a large amount of data from a CakePHP (v2.3.3) form, the $this->request->data array contains only some of the data (approximately the first 1000 values).

Does CakePHP truncate this array? What can I do to get the rest of the data?

(I've tried increasing post_max_size in php.ini, to no effect.)

Thanks.

Comment: How are you sending this _data_? Show us some code...

Comment: Thanks Leonardo.  I've found the problem, by looking in apache_error.log, which reports:  PHP Warning:  Unknown: Input variables exceeded 1000. To increase the limit change max_input_vars in php.ini.

Comment: You're probably sending the data with the GET method, try using POST.

Comment: The data was sent via POST, the default according to the CakePHP FormHelper documentation. In any event, I've added a new line to php.ini - "max_input_vars = 10000" - and all data is now being returned. Thanks, again, for your help.

Comment: @seqal you may want to post that as an answer :)